# output error iterating through list

Tags: python, list, loops

Am having some trouble with one of my classes. This particular class is supposed to calculate the moving average given a list (containing dates and prices) and no. of days(input by user). Here is my code:

```
class Moving_Average:

def calculation(self, alist:list,days:int):
    m = days
    prices = [float(i) for i in alist[1::2]]
    average = [0]* len(prices)
    signal = ['']* len(prices)
    for m in range(0,len(prices)-days+1):
        average[m+2] = sum(prices[m:m+days])/days
        if prices[m+2] < average[m+2]:
            signal[m+2]='SELL'
        elif prices[m+2] > average[m+2] and prices[m+1] < average[m+1]:
            signal[m+2]='BUY'
        else:
            signal[m+2] =''
    average = [round(average[i],2) for i in range(0,len(average))]
    return average,signal
```

This works fine when I want to calculate the average for 3 days. But when I try to calculate the average giving 2 days as input it gives me a Index Error. When I try to input 4 as the number of days, the result is as follows:

```
[0, 0, 33.81, 33.74, 33.51, 33.31, 33.28, 33.49, 33.85, 34.21, 34.43, 34.62, 34.75,   
34.88, 34.86, 34.57, 34.26, 34.45, 34.69, 35.13, 35.59, 35.51, 0], ['', '', '', '', 
'SELL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'BUY', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'BUY', 
'', 'SELL', 'BUY', ''])
```

when it should be:

```
[0, 0, 0, 33.81, 33.74, 33.51, 33.31, 33.28, 33.49, 33.85, 34.21, 34.43, 34.62, 34.75, 
34.88, 34.86, 34.57, 34.26, 34.45, 34.69, 35.13, 35.59, 35.51], ['', '', '', '', 
'SELL', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'BUY', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'SELL', 'SELL', 'BUY', 
'', 'SELL', 'BUY', ''])
```

i.e it adds an 0 in the end instead of the beginning.

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback of your exception? It should show exactly where the error is happening, which will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a `deque` with a `maxlen=days` to calculate your moving average? Also, instead of pre-allocating your output lists, just build them as you go. Avoid indexing into your lists or iterating using `range()`; if you find yourself doing that a lot, especially with calculations for indexes, you're probably doing it the hard way.

```
import collections

class MovingAverage(object)::

    def calculate(self, alist, days=2):

        averages = []
        signals  = []
        days     = float(days)   # make sure average is always float
        prices   = [float(n) for n in alist[1::2]]
        window   = collections.deque(maxlen=days)

        # generate moving averages and signals
        for price in prices:
           window.append(price)
           averages.append(0)
           signals.append("")
           if len(window) == days:   # window is full, we can calc moving avg
               mavg = sum(window) / days
               averages[-1] = mavg
               if price < mavg:
                    signals[-1] = "SELL"
                elif price > mavg:
                    signals[-1] = "BUY"

        averages[:] = ("%.2f" % a for a in averages)
        averages[:days] = [""] * days

        return averages, signals
```

Comment: thanks Kindall..what exactly is the averages[-1] = mavg doing?

Comment: Index -1 of a list refers to the last item. Basically, we're appending 0 every time through the loop, and then if we have seen enough items to calculate the moving average, we *change* that 0 to the calculated moving average. We could use an `if/else` to change what gets appended, but the signals list works better with this approach so I used the same one for the averages.

Comment: Kindall when i use this..some of the values are printed like 0.0, 23.2, 34.34...when i want them to be counting the ending zero's like 0.00, 23.20, 34.34 and so on..how can i do this. Also the first line should be empty if the average days is input as 2.

Comment: You need to convert them to strings, formatting them with the desired number of decimal places. You can do this either when printing or when building the `averages` list depending on what you want. For example: `averages[:] = ("%.2f" % avg for avg in averages)` in place of the next to last line.

Comment: how do i make the the days before the user input dates to be empty instead of 0?

Comment: I'll just change it so the `results` list is all strings... empty strings for the non-calculated values, formatted numbers with two decimal points for the calculated values. Later: done!

Comment: @Kindall- the output generated by this method signals BUY whenever the closing price on a day is higher than the moving average but it doesn't check if the previous days close was lower than moving average or not.  The condition to buy is: closing prices for that day has to be higher than the moving average and the closing price for the previous day has to be lower than the previous days moving average.

Comment: Resorted to post-processing again.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The index error happens in the loop, since you're trying to access the element `average[m+2]`, where `average` is of length `len(prices)`, but the value of `m` is `len(prices) - 2` (assuming `days == 2`), so `m == len(prices)` and is outside the range of the list.

You never access the first element of `average`, and you never write the first or second elements of `average` or `signal`. Perhaps this is why you're getting the extra zero in the `days == 4` case. Remember that Python uses zero-based indexing.

Personally, I don't think it's a good idea to have your dates and prices all in one long list. A list of date-price tuples would be better. Also, the line `m = days` at the top of the script does nothing, so it should be removed.